# The solution to the non-linear convection equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differential-equations, non-linear-systems, convection

The non-linear convection equation

$$u_{t} +uu_{x}=0$$ admits implicit solutions of the form $$u=f(x-ut).$$
How does one interpret this solution intuitively? Is there an example of a solution of this equation that can  be written in an explicit form? How does an initial function evolve over time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This quasi-linear 1st-order [PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation) 
   $$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)_{\!x} + u\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)_{\!t}~=~0\tag{1}$$
   is the [inviscid Burgers' equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation).
2. It can be solved via the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). The [ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation) [IVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem) 
   $$ \frac{dx}{dt}~=~u, \qquad x(t\!=\!0)~=~\xi, \tag{2}$$
   (where $u$ is treated as an external parameter and $\xi$ is an initial value) has integral curves
   $$ x(t) ~=~ u t + \xi. \tag{3}$$
   The initial value $\xi$ and the external parameter $u$ label the integral curves (3) in an $(t,x)$-diagram.
3. A solution $u(x,t)$ to the PDE is constant along above integral curves (3):
   $$ \frac{du(x(t),t)}{dt}~=~\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)_{\!x} + \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)_{\!t}\frac{dx}{dt}~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~ \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)_{\!x} + u\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)_{\!t}~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~0.\tag{4}$$
   This leads to that the solution $u=f(\xi)$ should be a function of $\xi$.
4. The function 
   $$x\quad \mapsto\quad f(x)~=~u(x,t\!=\!0)\tag{5}$$ 
   is the initial profile.
5. The implicit solution 
   $$u(x,t)~=~f(x-t u(x,t))~=~f(x-t f(x-t u(x,t)))~=~\ldots\tag{6}$$
   is a fixed-point equation.
6. Interestingly, the non-linear PDE can develop shock-wave singular solution $u$ from a smooth regular initial profile $f$.
7. *Example.* The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation) lists the full solution 
   $$u(x,t)~=~\frac{ax+b}{at+1}\tag{7}$$ for the initial profile 
   $$f(x)~=~ax+b.\tag{8}$$